# Unable to import tensorflow with error "No module named 'tensorflow.python.distribute.load_context'"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-import, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to import tensorflow with the following command :

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

However, I keep getting the following error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File c:\Users\Lenovo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.0\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:45
     42 from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
     43 _tf2.enable()
---> 45 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
     46 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __operators__
     47 from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

File c:\Users\Lenovo\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.0\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py:27
     25 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import train
     26 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import types
---> 27 from tensorflow.python.distribute.load_context import load_context # line: 49
     28 from tensorflow.python.eager.backprop import record_gradient # line: 160
     29 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import is_tfrt_enabled # line: 124

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.distribute.load_context'
```

My python version is 3.11.0 and tensorflow version is 2.15.0.

Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing anaconda and create an environment using Anaconda prompt.
After creating the environment install the library using: pip install tensorflow and run your program from the environment.

Comment: Will this work with venv?

Comment: As long as you have the library installed inside the environment it should be alright.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my original question... I should be able to import and use tensorflow outside of a virtual environment.

Comment: Creating a new environment is not necessary, you could install the package with pip in your current environment, and then try again.